# PMD with Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I installed the pmd-eclipse (v0.9) and was having jre6 on my machine. Read about that PMD doesn't support jre6 or lower so installed the jre7 and then set the Jre on Eclipse to the same. At the project level did the PMD enable for this project check-box. But after that for each class the PMD option is not appearing. Please assist.

Comment: What is "the PMD option"?

Comment: PMD does not require JRE 7, just [Java 5 or higher](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/installing.html).

Answer (score 1):

You only have to enable PMD in the project properties. There is no PMD option for each class.

It sounds like you didn't add a PMD rule set file. If you don't already have a PMD rule set file then you have to [create one](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtomakearuleset.html) first. You can add a PMD rule set file by clicking the "Add..." button on the PMD property page of your project's properties dialog. If your PMD property page looks something like the following then eclipse-pmd will analyze all classes in the project.

[image: eclipse-pmd property page with rule sets]

The eclipse-pmd website also provides step-by-step instructions on [how to set up eclipse-pmd](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/getting-started.html) correctly.